# Get Camera resolution in Flex Builder

Tags: get, resolution, flashbuilder4

I am developing an application using Flex Builder and i am a newbie to it...
My task is to develop an application using flex builder having two cameras 1 for video chat and one for capturing images and send it to the friend with whom you are chatting....

I have developed the application and written a script for it...but i am facing a problem that if i am having an arrays of camera then how i will get to know that which one is HD cam and which one is normal web cam... and according to it i have to set the cameras for chatting and capturing ....

so my question is how can i set the HD cam in my application if we have two cameras simultaneously. Is there any built in function to know the resultion or something like that....